# How can I set up timer in Swift?

Tags: swift, timer, nstimer

I have a pickerController set the hours, minutes and seconds but I don't know how to set up my timer, this is the Code I have, but it doesn't work, how can I change that? Thank's in advance

```
func startTimer() {
    if timer.isValid == true || timeHours == 0  || timeMinutes == 0 || timeSeconds == 0 {
        //do nothing
    } else {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(onTimerFires), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}
```

---

```
@objc func onTimerFires() {
    timeHours -= 1
    timeMinuteLabel.text = timeFunc()
    if timeSeconds == 0 {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}  



func timeFunc() -> String {
    let hours = Int(optionalValuePickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)) 
    let minutes = Int(optionalValuePickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1))
    let seconds = Int(optionalValuePickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 2)) 
    return String(format: "%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)
}
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is notoriously unhelpful.  What do you expect it to do and what does it do instead of that?

Comment: @PhillipMills In the timeFunc() function I take the values from my PickerView and give it to the timer as hours, minutes and seconds, The problem is that when I run it, the timer does nothing, the hours, minutes and seconds are still not changing. That is my problem, I don't know how to make it to a useful functioning timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

- Every time `onTimerFires` is called, it is decrementing `timeHours` (which does not appear to be set or used anywhere) and then calls `timeFunc`, which just grabs values from the picker (which are not changing anywhere) to build the string.
- This pattern of decrementing a counter in a timer makes a big assumption, namely that the timer is invoked exactly at the right time and that it will not ever miss a timer call. That is not a prudent assumption, unfortunately.
- I would advise against the `Selector` based timer, as that introduces a strong reference cycle with the `target`. The block-based rendition with `weak` references is easier to avoid these sorts of cycles.

I would suggest a different pattern, namely that you save the time to which you are counting down:

```
var countDownDate: Date!

func updateCountDownDate() {
    let components = DateComponents(hour: pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0),
                                    minute: pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1),
                                    second: pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 2))

    countDownDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to: Date())
}
```

Then your timer handler can calculate the amount of elapsed time to the target count down date/time:

```
func handleTimer(_ timer: Timer) {
    let remaining = countDownDate.timeIntervalSince(Date())

    guard remaining >= 0 else {
        timer.invalidate()
        return
    }

    label.text = timeString(from: remaining)
}
```

When you start the timer, you calculate the `countDownDate` and schedule the timer:

```
weak var timer: Timer?

func startTimer() {
    timer?.invalidate() // if one was already running, cancel it

    updateCountDownDate()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
        guard let self = self else {
            timer.invalidate()
            return
        }

        self.handleTimer(timer)
    }
    timer?.fire()
}
```

And, for what is worth, when preparing the string, you certainly can determine the date components between to dates (i.e., now and your target date/time), but you can also use a `DateComponentsFormatter` do this for you:

```
let formatter: DateComponentsFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.unitsStyle = .positional
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
    formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
    return formatter
}()

func timeString(from interval: TimeInterval) -> String? {
    return formatter.string(from: interval)
}
```